# Processing batch of differently-shaped tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, mapping, gpu

Suppose we have a batch of images as 4D tensor of shape `(batches, height, width, channels)`. And suppose we have some images transforming functions `f0(img...)`, `f1(img...)` `...`, each function processes just one image (not batch) represented as 3D tensor. Also output tensors from this functions may be different in shape than input tensors, even some of functions may produce more than one tensor and functions may have some extra arguments besides image.

Also suppose that we have [non-eager](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) execution mode, meaning that we build a graph to `.pb` file first and later graph is executed mostly on [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) for efficiency.

As it is common for TF, first `batches` dimension size might be unknown, which is signified by value `None`. Real size of this dimension is only known at graph evaluation time on input data (user may try to feed batches of varying sizes).

We're given a sequence of required image transformations specified as the list of functions with extra arguments. The task is to somehow process input batch of images through these functions. More than that it is needed to do in most efficient way, [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)s are not allowed, meaning that if all transforming functions are implemented and run on GPU-side only then it is not allowed for intermediate results to go back and forth from gpu to cpu as inputs to `py_function`s.

The main difficulty is due to batches count being not known (equal to `None`). Hence we can't use python loop to processs each image through function. Of cause we can fix some maximum possible batch size and create a loop up to this maximum size, and for loop iterations when there is no input we can conditionally not process this input and pass empty tensor forth. Another problem that on each stage input and output list length may be different, e.g. when image transofmation splits input image into 3-4 unequal in shape tensors or does multi-crop with different windows.

I think the right approach would be to use [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) somehow, but I haven't understood how it works, and how to apply this while to case when each stage has different length of possible tensors of different shape.

There is [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) which is perfect for the case when all inputs have same shape and outputs too. Then we can pass down the transofmation path single 4D tensor. But this is not the case, inputs can be different in shapes and outputs too.

Maybe there is anything like python's `list` but in TF side? Meaning list to keep tensors of different shape, but TF-only, which doesn't leave GPU like python list does. If there exists such list and there is analogy of [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) then we can use this mapping to process list of tensors of different shape, by applying one function. It partially and mostly would solve my task, at least help me for sure.

Comment: you know the size of your batch when create the input tensor, why don't you use that in your python for loops?  if you need to figure out the batch size for tf ops during runtime you can use `dynamic_batch_size = tf.shape(batch_of_images_as_4D_tensor)[0]`

Comment: @j314erre I told that it is `non-eager` execution, meaning that graph is built to `.pb` and only then graph code is run on GPU, so during graph construction python can't know the real batch size, and there is no python on gpu at all, so for python processing data should be transfered back and forth from gpu to cpu, which is not allowed because the task is to be very efficient.